# jQuery: Script suddenly stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I looked through the questions about jQuery and scripts stop working. But it seems, they don't fit my problem:

When I switch view on my Android smartphone, the scroll.js stops working. The links wont even "jump" to their destination ...

Here's the index.html:

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/scroll.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/lightbox.css"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/computer.css" media="screen and (min-width:981px)"></link>

        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/tablet-portrait.css" media="screen and (max-width:980px)"> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/tablet-landscape.css" media="screen and (max-width:)"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone-portrait.css" media="screen and (max-width:720px)">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone-landscape.css" media="screen and (max-width:)"> -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var next_move = "expand";
            $(document).ready(function (){
            if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 720px)').matches) {
                    $("#icon-menu").on('click',function(){
                        if (next_move == "expand"){
                            $("#navigation").animate({left: '50%'});
                            $("body").animate({left: '50%'});
                            next_move = "shrink";
                    } else {
                        $("#navigation").animate({left: '0%'});
                        $("body").animate({left: '0%'});
                        next_move = "expand";
                    }
                    });
            }
            else{

            }
            });
        </script>

    </head>
```

and the scroll.js:

```
 $(function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click',function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

What ever is going on there is just happening to Chrome (I guess all webkit browsers) and the android-browser. When I open it with Firefox, scrolling works, menu expand doesn't.
I tried the .noConflict(), but it just did, that the links jump to their destination and the menu wasn't expanding anymore.

For the view: [click me](http://testumgebung.tf-design.de)

Please ignore things like the device-width. It's not finished yet, but I have to test it.

So the real question:
What am I doing wrong? If there are conflicts, where can I find and correct them?

To reproduce the problem, just resize the browser to a smartphone size and refresh or use the smartphone instead. Otherwise the site is displayed for pc, where everthing works fine.

Edit: On the pc in smartphone-view everything works with Firefox, but on the actual smartphone the menu won't expand ...

Thank you!

Comment: Not that it will make a difference, but please note you have two document ready handlers. `$(function(){});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function{});` :)

Comment: Try to bind events with on('click', function() {...
And try to rebind it $(window).on('orientationchange' and $(window).on('resize'...

Comment: So, in this case 
  $("#icon-menu").on('click', function(){}
?
Sorry, a bit new to this stuff ...

Comment: If you are ever having scope issues, you can use this instead `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE });` which does both a DOM ready handler and provides a locally scoped `$`

Comment: Also, the appropriate way for setting `setTimeout` code to execute is `setTimeout(function() { $('#loading').hide(); }, 1500);`

Comment: I also note your `setTimeout( "$('#loading').hide();",1500 );` is dependent on the DOM being ready within 1.5 seconds (which it may not be). Put that inside the DOM ready handler too.

Comment: @Julia `$("#icon-menu").on('click', function() { });` is just the same to `$("#icon-menu").click(function() { });`.

Comment: @Regent: Providing Javascript functions as strings is perfectly valid and shorter (if slightly odd looking) :)

Comment: Okay. I did all that, except for the `$(window).on('orientationchange' and $(window).on('resize'...` - thing (because atm I don't really know, how to use it, but I'll keep that in mind). Still no scroll-reaction from Chrome, and no menu-reaction from Firefox (second works on pc but not on smartphone).

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce the problem? I am using Chrome and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Resize the browser-window to a smartphone-like size. At least, that's how I can see it on the pc. In the smartphone case, it happens to me just by opening the site.
In the pc-view it does work fine ...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie there is nothing about string code in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) there is: _alternate syntax is a string of code you want to execute after delay milliseconds (using this syntax is_ **not recommended** _for the same reasons as using eval())_. Lets just say it's definitely not good (not appropriate) way to set code for execution :)

Comment: @Regent: Okay, your use of the term `appropriate` is *appropriate*. :) The time difference is insignificant on that one-shot function, but we should not encourage bad habits. It is *valid* to provide that function as a string, but it is not recommended.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes :) I actually don't know what is wrong in provided code (and changing from `$('html,body')` to `$('body')` will probably not help either), so I can only talk about "bad" places in code...

Comment: @Julia if `this.hash.slice(1)` returns single word, it shouldn't be a problem. But I actually don't know whether `#12345` is valid hash or not. I don't see any reasons why it can be incorrect, but who knows...

Comment: Didn't change anything ... unfortunately.

Comment: `target.offset().top` somewhy returns -1600, -2300 and so on in mobile view. But even setting `scrollTop: 0` doesn't seem to work. And it's twice strange.

Comment: So, the only thing left to consider: Don't use scroll.js for mobile-views? 
I now would throw the scroll.js in the else of the width condition. 
As I deleted to import scroll.js, Chrome jumped to it's destinations and the menu was expanding, too.

Comment: What I actually don't like is that `scrollTop: 0` doesn't work. I don't even imagine why it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Haha ... ha. Slowly I'm losing my patience ... As I mentioned, I put the scroll-code in the first else condition. Everything works perfectly. But: Mobile Firefox keeps using it. Or is it just me?
(edited in the code above)

Comment: Have you tried adding jQuery mobile and bind `tap` event along with `click`? `$(document).on('click tap', 'selector', function(){})`

Comment: May it be just a stupid, stupid conflict between a code and the expand/shrink-code nobody's able to find? No matter what, I can't leave Firefox out ... so many people use it ...

Comment: @Justinas event is actually triggered. The problem is in `.animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 1000);`

Comment: And the Firefox menu is the problem :/ I can live without the smooth scrolling on mobiles.

Comment: @Julia I have just tested site in Firefox 31.0 - arrow works correctly both in normal and mobile view, but on page width about 600px all styles have just disappeared o_O In Opera the same from 720px to 980px.

Comment: I don't know - maybe you should include not found file _http://testumgebung.tf-design.de/js/lightbox.min.map_

Comment: Oh that's okay. The "tablet"-view is not finished yet. So only mobile-view till 720px and pc-view from 981px.
And on the PC with resized browser, everything works more or less, but with an actual mobile it won't. Like I'm in the twilight zine Q.Q

Comment: Alright, I figured the Firefox problem out. Mobile Firefox seems to send back other resolutions than Chrome. With max/min-device-width, it's working. :D

Comment: And what about the problem with arrow scrolling?

Comment: If the scroll-code isn't used for mobile, everything's fine. At least on mine.

Comment: So can we say that it finally more or less works? I actually don't see mobile styles on site now (with 482px width).

Comment: Because of the device-width it will only show that way if the whole device has the width. So a PC monitor nowadays may not reach the 719px to show (width vs. resolution you might say). Same with mobiles: iPhone e.g. has a width x height of 640px x 960px (resolution) and a device-width x -height of 320px x 480px.
And yes, we can say that. I post it as an answer, even it's not exactly the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully answered.

One solution was, to ignore the smooth scrolling for mobile devices.
So, the code atm looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/lightbox.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/computer.css" media="screen and (min-device-width:981px)"></link>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/tablet-portrait.css" media="screen and (max-width:980px)"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/tablet-landscape.css" media="screen and (max-width:)"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone-portrait.css" media="screen and (max-device-width:720px)">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/phone-landscape.css" media="screen and (max-width:)"> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var next_move = "expand";
        $(document).ready(function (){
        if (window.matchMedia('(max-device-width: 720px)').matches) {
                $("#icon-menu").on('click',function(){
                    if (next_move == "expand"){
                        $("#navigation").animate({left: '50%'});
                        $("body").animate({left: '50%'});
                        next_move = "shrink";
                } else {
                    $("#navigation").animate({left: '0%'});
                    $("body").animate({left: '0%'});
                    next_move = "expand";
                }
                });
        }
        else{
            $(function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click',function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                    if (target.length) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        }
        });
    </script>
```

So the link and menu problems are gone, but the wanted smooth scroll effect for mobiles, too, is still not working.

Maybe someone has a clue.

To see the mobile-view a device with a width (not resolution!) of 720px is needed.